# from byte to bitmap c#

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to convert bytes to bitmap here is my code  the code is about recieving image from mobile and uploaded into a remote server :sql server : this is the function which implement the interface below:

```
public wsSQLResult CreateImage(Stream JSONdataStream) { 
    wsSQLResult result = new wsSQLResult();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(JSONdataStream);
    string JSONdata = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // ..then convert the string into a single "wsCustomer" record.
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    wsClass1 cust = jss.Deserialize<wsClass1>(JSONdata);
    if (cust == null)
    {
        result.message = "Unable to deserialize the JSON data.";
        return result;
    }

    pictureDataContext dc = new pictureDataContext();
    fff  user = (from p
                 in dc.fff
                 where (p.id == cust.getid)
                 select p).FirstOrDefault();
    if (user == null)
    {
        byte[] toDecodeByte = Convert.FromBase64String(cust.getpic);

        UploadDocument( toDecodeByte );
        fff newCustomer = new fff()
            {
                id = cust.getid,
                title = cust.gettitle,
                picture = toDecodeByte
            };

        dc.fff.InsertOnSubmit(newCustomer);
        dc.SubmitChanges();

        result.message = "thanks for regestring you may now login";
        return result;
    }

    result.message = "thanks for regestring you may now logijj";
    return result;
}
```

here is the interface  please any help and thnkx a lot:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Image", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
 wsSQLResult CreateImage(Stream JSONdataStream);
```

i will be so glad for your help.

Comment: I also have an exception in this instruction : in the uploadDocument method

Comment: exactly here  using (Bitmap bm2 = new Bitmap(ms))

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code 

Additional information: The parameter is not valid....

Comment: @Loetn  An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The parameter is not valid

Comment: The line you mentioned isn't even _in_ that code. And if you just receive bytes and put them in the database, why bother processing them as image? Just leave it a byte array.